# Ajax Modalpop up error

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have added a modal popextender 
when i click on Edit button i ma getting following error.

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 55504 in http://localhost:59846/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '_events' of undefined or null reference

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 55504 in http://localhost:59846/bundles/MsAjaxJs?

Comment: Can you provide any page markup? What version of Ajax Control toolkit do you use?

Comment: Could you please edit your markup and remove all specific code from it so one can run it? Also, code-behind will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have  two pages View.aspx and AddEdit.aspx

On click of Edit button of View.aspx , Another page AddEdit.aspx in Modalpopup should be opened.
I am using AjaxControlTookit version 15.1.3.0

View.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="View.aspx.cs" Inherits="TransitionAutomationPlatform.WebApp.Templates.ContractSummaryNote.View" %>

<%@ Register Src="../../UserControls/ucProcessInfo.ascx" TagName="ucProcessInfo" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="../../UserControls/ucGridActions.ascx" TagName="ucGridActions" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .DarkenBackground {
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0.7; /* Safari, Opera */
            filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* IE */
            z-index: 20;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-repeat: repeat;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }

        .ModalPopup {
            background-color: #003e74;
            filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* IE */
            font-family: Verdana;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0.75pt;
            border-color: White;
        }

            .ModalPopup h {
                background-color: #003e74;
                filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* IE */
                font-family: Verdana;
            }

        .GridViewFixedHeader {
            position: relative;
            color: White;
            background-color: #646464;
        }

        .GridScrollBar {
            overflow-y: auto;
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .DefaultCursor {
            cursor: default;
        }

        .MainPageTable {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .ModalTable {
            height: 100%;
            width: 95%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .ModalTableLabelTD {
            font-size: 8pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: White;
            width: 25%;
        }

        .ModalTableControlTD {
            width: 160px;
        }

        .GridViewResult {
            background-color: White;
            width: 282px;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .GridViewResultRows {
            color: Black;
            background-color: White;
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="../../Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../Content/TableTools.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="../Datatables_Latest/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <%--  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>--%>

    <script src="../../Scripts/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Datatables_Latest/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/General.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/JsTemplates/ContractSummaryNote.js"></script>




    <div>
        <uc1:ucProcessInfo ID="ucProcessInfo1" runat="server" />
    </div>

   <%-- <div style="float: right">
        <uc2:ucGridActions ID="ucGridActions1" runat="server" />
    </div>--%>

    <br />
    <div>

        <table>
            <thead class="gridHeader">

            </thead>
        </table>
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>

                        <input id="btnEdit" type="button" value="button" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" runat="server" />
                        <div id="demo">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>
                        </div>
                        <br />



                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>


    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"
        runat="server" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
        OkControlID="btnOkay" TargetControlID="btnEdit"
        PopupControlID="Panel1" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader"
        Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="DarkenBackground">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <div class="popupConfirmation" id="Panel1" style="display: none">
        <iframe id="frameeditexpanse" src="AddEdit.aspx" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <div class="popup_Buttons" style="display: none">
            <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done" />
            <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

AddEdit.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddEdit.aspx.cs" Inherits="TransitionAutomationPlatform.WebApp.Templates.ContractSummaryNote.AddEdit" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
     <link href="../../Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../Content/TableTools.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="../../Scripts/General.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/JsTemplates/ContractSummaryNote.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/ZeroClipboard/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="../../Scripts/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>--%>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="../../Scripts/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="../../Scripts/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/dataTables.editor.js"></script>




    <div class="popup_Container">
        <div class="popup_Titlebar" id="PopupHeader">
            <div class="TitlebarLeft">
                Edit Expanse
            </div>
            <div class="TitlebarRight" onclick="cancel();">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="popup_Body">
           <div id="dialog-message" title="Contract Summary Note Details">
                        <table>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;" class="ModalTable">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Document Name<span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" id="txtDocumentName" maxlength="50" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Clause No<span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" id="txtClauseNo" maxlength="50" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Page No <span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" id="txtPageNo" maxlength="50" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Linl EPM Task<span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="ddlEPMTaskName" id="ddlEPMTaskName"></select>
                                                <%--  <a href="javascript:void(0);"  id="hreflink">Group Details</a>--%>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Due Date as per Project Plan</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" id="txtDueDate" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Function Name <span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="ddlFunctionName" id="ddlFunctionName"></select>
                                                <%-- <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="hreflink">Group Details</a>--%>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Owner</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" id="txtOwner" />
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Activity at risk of missing Contracted Due Date</td>
                                                <td>

                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkIsActivityAtRisk" value="" checked="checked" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Status <span style="color: red;">*</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="ddlStatus" id="ddlStatus"></select>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </div>
            edit data
        </div>
        <div class="popup_Buttons">
            <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done" runat="server" />
            <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>









</asp:Content>

<%-- Reference for Js file --%>
```